# Calculating the MTBF (mean time between failure)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate the MTBF for machine (mean time between failure). Where, `event_type = 0` is when machine added or on, and `event_type= 1` is when machine failed. `MTBF = Time/number_of_failure`.

My query is calculating the MTBF by taking each time period and dividing by the total number of failure in **all dataset**, not total number of failure that happen **up to time period**.

I hope I explain the issue smoothly

The expected result of MTBF in following table:

```
machine_type_id   time        machine_id     event_type     MTBF
6298               0            6640223           0         0
28602         1.82296E+12       6640223           1    1.82296E+12
28610         1.82396E+12       6640223           0    1.82396E+12
33362         2.23891E+12       6640223           1    1.11946E+12
33409         2.2393E+12        6640223           0    1.11965E+12
```

My query:

```
select m.machine_id, m.time , m.time/sum(tet.total_failure) as MTBF
    from
    (
        select machine_id, time,  count(*) as total_failure from machine_events 
        where event_type=1
        group by machine_id, time

    ) as tet inner join machine_events as m on m.machine_id = tet.machine_id
    group by m.machine_id, m.time
    order by m.time
```

**I hope you can provide a simple query, so then I can write function that pass `time` , `machine id` to get `MTBF`.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SELECT 
    m.machine_id, 
    m.time, 
    m.time / CASE WHEN ( SUM (m.event_type % 2) OVER( PARTITION BY m.machine_id ORDER BY m.time ) ) = 0 THEN 1 
                  ELSE ( SUM (m.event_type % 2) OVER( PARTITION BY m.machine_id ORDER BY m.time ) ) END as MTBF
FROM 
    machine_events m
ORDER BY
    m.machine_id, m.time
```

Comment: I got "Divide by zero error encountered". Let me first solve it

Comment: There are event_type = 2 in dataset which represent machine updated, so under your solution it might it calculate it, maybe write event_type !=2 will solve this

Comment: i added %2 and count 2 as zero